# In a Jenkins pipeline, how can I keep track which child module in a Git submodule has a certain branch?

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Say I have a Git submodule, and have created a branch with the same name on some, but NOT ALL, of its child modules. Here's the file structure.

```
/path/submodule/module1
               /module2 <---- has feature/jira-123-new-feature branch
               /module3
               /module4 <---- has feature/jira-123-new-feature branch
```

So in the case above, child modules `module2` and `module4` have the `feature/jira-123-new-feature` branch, but not `module1` and `module3`.

In a Jenkins pipeline, I want to be able to do this.

```
node("buildNode") {
  stage("Run Git") {
    List<String> childModules = []
    sh """
      git submodule foreach 'git checkout feature/jira-123-new-feature && <add child module to childModules list> || :'
    """
  }
}
```

The idea is if the child module has the branch, `git checkout feature/jira-123-new-feature` will pass and the code for `<add child module to childModules list>` will execute. Otherwise the `git checkout ...` will fail, but the `|| :` will catch it and move onto the next child module.

My question is, how can I code `<add child module to childModules list>`? Or maybe is there even a better/different way to accomplish what I need? TIA

Answer (score 0):

I did the following, though I honestly think someone will have a better way.

```
      // Store the child modules with "branchToBuild" in a file called
      // "dirs.txt"
      sshagent(credentials: ['bitbucket-creds']) {
        sh(label: "Build",
           script: """
             if [ -f dirs.txt ]; then rm -f dirs.txt; fi
             git submodule foreach 'git checkout $branchToBuild && git pull origin $branchToBuild && echo \$name >> ../dirs.txt || :'
           """,
           returnStatus: true)
      }

      // Now read the "dirs.txt" file into a list 
      final List<String> modules = (readFile(file: "./dirs.txt")).split("\n")
      modules.each { module ->
        // Do something
      }
```